# Counting fields from related table WITH Where Statement

Tags: ms-access-2007

I would like to count fields from related table with WHERE Statement.

For counting data from related table I used this statement.

```
=DCount("ID","Customers","AddressID=" & AddressID)
```

I have to count customers for each address that customer is registred with WHERE statement where I will check how many customers are banned for each address.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can build up the where statement like so:

```
=DCount("ID","Customers","Banned = False And AddressID=" & AddressID)
=DCount("ID","Customers","Banned = 'No' And AddressID=" & AddressID)
=DCount("ID","Customers","Banned = ""No"" And AddressID=" & AddressID)
=DCount("ID","Customers","DateBanned = #2012/09/21# And AddressID=" & AddressID)
```

The third argument of domain aggregate functions such as [DCount](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa211471%28v=office.11%29.aspx) is the where statement (criteria), and you can use most of the expressions that you would use in a query in that argument.

Comment: And If my Banned field is Text?

Comment: Use quotes, just as you would with a where atatement.